# Make child div height to 100% of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have searched all over google, stackoverflow and other forms and websites yet I cannot find a solution. None of what I found worked for me.

(Question related Website: http://rikahiyuka.com )

Abbreviations:

`#DivC` is the content box to the left under the header and above the footer.

`#DivSB` is the content box to the right under the header and above the footer.

`#DivWC` is the container of both `#DivC` and `#DivSB` which is invisible.

My HTML structures looks like this:

```
<div id="WC">
    <div id="SB">...</div>
    <div id="C">...</div>
</div>
```

Notes:

`#DivWC` height will automatically resize to the longest div out of `#DivC` and `#DivSB` (using `overflow:hidden`)

`#DivSB` has `float:right` CSS property.

---

I am trying to make it so that `#DivC` will automatically resize to `#DivWC` height.
I want to do the same for `#DivSB` so that if either `#DivC` or `#DivSB` is taller, `#DivWC` will have the height of the tallest box, then the other box (shorter box from `#DivC` or `#DivSB`) will resize to `#DivWC` height.

Setting all parent elements to `height:100%` caused the content box to have an height of 100 viewpoint height.

I have tried using `display:table` and `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` but those completely destroy the layout.

I have seen a few uses of absolute positioning, but from what I know, absolute positioning is ignored by other elements, so I don't think absolute positioning will work because there may be more boxes added on other pages and the footer will not be in the right place.

I am looking for a solution that uses CSS and HTML(5).
Without the use of adding an image or using Javascript.

I still have little knowledge on webcoding so if you can, please make your answer(s) simple or explain (as far as possible) every step (I understand and learn better with explanations).

Comment: In order to adjust the height we have to use JavaScript.But you can consider using "min-height" css property.So that both the boxes will have equal height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make that happen by displaying `#DivWC` as table, and `#DivC` and `#DivSB` as table-cells. Change their CSS to:

Note: don't forget to swap the positions of `#DivC` and `#DivSB`.

```
/* *** Content *** */

#DivWC{
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20px;
    height:100%; /* delete if you want it to only take the height it needs (based on children's content */
    background-color:purple;
    display: table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px;
}

/* *** Content (Content) *** */

#DivC{
    background-color:#D4E9EB;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:10px;
    display: table-cell;
}

/* *** SideBar (Content) *** */

#DivSB{
    background-color:#D4E9EB;
    border-radius:15px;
    width:150px;
    padding:10px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Doing this causes the content within 'box1' (DivC) to get pushed down for the height of the sidebar ('box2' or DivSB). Also the heights of both content divs ('box1','box2') doesn't match. Thanks for answering thought.

Comment: I understood your question that you want `#DivC`, `#DivWC` and `#DivSB` to all be the same height... works for me: http://i42.tinypic.com/numo1.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much, your help is highly appreciated. After reading and comparing the code in your answer and my stylesheet for the 5th time, I think I have made sense about what each line does. It did what I asked for and I should now know how to use this for other layouts for sub topic pages. Once again, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="WC">
    <div id="C">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="SB">Lorem ipsum @RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    height: 20px;
}

#WC {
    background-color: #ffc;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#WC > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
#SB {
    background-color: #cfc;
    width: 100px;
}
#C  {
    background-color: #ccf;
    width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jjG4y/1/